# Searching about an example about SpeechRocognizer Android 2.2 class use

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-2.2-froyo

If you have any sample code about that class, i'm interested.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android speech recognition resource page: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

Example source code for a simple app using speech recognition:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

I'm not sure what you mean by the `SpeechRecognizer` class. It doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Ok, I knew this example but it's older than SpeechRecognizer (2.2) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Comment: Well you're right about `SpeechRecognizer`. Sorry I missed that. Did I answer your question?

Comment: My problem is having working speech recognition with a bluetooth device. The android 2.2 specifications tells it's possible but there's no example of how implements that.